# PHPExcel Reader Date Format Issue - rangeToArray

Tags: php, excel, date

I am facing a Date format issue when reading excel using PHPExcel. 
Even I used `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);` getting format of the cell but not working for me.
This how I am reading the data from Excel.

```
$get_excel_data = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray("A1:".$highestColumn.$highestRow);
```

When I am trying to print date, it shows like 03/06/13, and I have tried to convert in mysl date format using

```
date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val[1])); // echoing 2036-03-06
```

But it is not working, Can anyone guide me to the issue ? The main problem is I am not getting the date as number format ( Excel ), Instead of it showing date as 03/06/13,

Comment: So what was the actual value and the format mask of the cell? Id there is a bug in PHPExcel, as you're suggesting, then those details are extremely important if I'm expected to fix the problem

Comment: @MarkBaker I am not sure about whether it a bug or not, since same excel I have worked by using $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $i)->getValue() and $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray("A1:".$highestColumn.$highestRow) , In first case Im getting the date field correctly, but this case date was not worked, that's why I have used same function. I hope you have seen my answer. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have solved the date issue

```
$get_excel_data = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray("A1:".$highestColumn.$highestRow);           
$i = 1; 
foreach($get_excel_data as $val) {
    //In my case, 2nd column is a date so that I format using 
    $date = date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $i)->getValue()));  // array index 1              
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $i)->getValue()));` output?

Comment: That is ok then. But what did `var_dump(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val[1]));` output in your question?

Comment: I have used echo date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val[1])); It echo 2036-03-06

Comment: I saw that in question; I am interested what did `var_dump(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val[1]));` output; or what does `var_dump($val);` output?

Comment: 03/06/13 this is the date now, Previously I was used some other date. I think problem with rangeToArray only.

Comment: So my answer `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val[1])));` was correct; but if you already get timestamp it is better to use it like this.

Answer (score 1):

If `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val[1]);` returns `03/06/13`, then this should work :

```
$date = new DateTime(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val[1]));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

or

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val[1])));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is not working. I have solved it in another way.

Comment: I have edited my answer, You misunderstood the result. Sorry,. I will be posting the answer which worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Glavić, seems from the question's comments that the `ExcelToPHP` is outputting a timestamp integer. I think `DateTime` has to be constructed with `"@".$timestamp` when it's a UNIX timestamp.